# Reading data from HID devices

Tags: hid, pywinusb

I am using pywinusb to read data from a device which is connected via usb.

I have used the following code to read the data.

https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/blob/master/examples/raw_data.py

Now the device is sending 3 packets of data but this is only catching only one packet of data. I need all the three packets.
How to solve this?

Maybe I need to change the length of the data it is capturing or maybe the baud rate. So, what is the solution?